# Meteor package accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 dropdown menu appears outside of the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am trying to follow the basic example of using Meteor (version 1.0.0) package "accounts-ui-bootstrap-3" as shown on their [github page](https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/). However, the dropdown menu shows up outside of the screen, as seen below:

[Dropbox link to the picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3stw2p0pexbpqes/error.tiff?dl=0)

I had read the following on accounts-ui package GitHub page:

> If you plan to position the login dropdown in the right edge of the screen, use {{> loginButtons align="right"}} in order to get the dropdown to lay itself out without expanding off the edge of the screen.

So I used the align="right" parameter in my HTML file. I have no additional CSS styling added. Below is the list of all the meteor packages installed:

- accounts-facebook                 1.0.2
- accounts-password                 1.0.4
- biasport:facebook-sdk             0.1.0
- chrismbeckett:fontawesome4        4.2.2
- flanamacca:summernote-standalone  1.0.1
- ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3       1.1.20
- insecure                          1.0.1
- iron:router                       1.0.1
- jquery                            1.0.1
- less                              1.0.11
- meteor-platform                   1.2.0
- nemo64:bootstrap                  3.2.3*
- service-configuration             1.0.2
- underscore

Trying the accounts-ui package seems to work perfectly fine, but I would like to use this particular package to get the bootstrap classes for all the components.

Why is it doing so and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install boostrap too, not just the accounts package.

Regards

Comment: I have added bootstrap (in particular, the package: nemo64:bootstrap 3.2.3*). I can even see the bootstrap classes working in my HTML, so I know it is installed correctly.